# Unity Oculus Android build fails.to launch Daemon

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, virtual-reality, oculus

Students in my classroom are using Unity to build apps for the Oculus Go. I can build to device without problemm but some permission setting is preventing students from building. They get this error. I think that security settings are preventing gradle from launching another thread. I'm not familiar enough with the actual build process to understand this. Any suggestions where to look would be appreciated. They have some pretty cool projects and are ready to test teleporting and other interactions.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
]
stdout[
:checkDebugClasspath
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:compileDebugRenderscript
:checkDebugManifest
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:prepareLintJar
:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources FAILED
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <177bc8179be6497489c4b5b319f290d7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Windows Universal C Runtime library.

You can find it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Currently working with Unity for Oculus Quest and went through several pitfalls ;°)
First, check the Android version (requires Android R26)

- Best workflow for me was to install android SDK through Unity's Hub. It's well hidden in the "download archive" page, there is a "hub" button near the version you want to download/update, from where you can pick the Android JDK and beneath, two additional checkboxes for the NDK ad SDK.
- Use "Build" or "Build&Run" from the Build Settings window, at least the *.apk is saved on disk, not the case with CRTL+B!
- Here the build operation can still fail to write on the device (works only if the app has been already removed on my side).
- You can then deploy the app with "adb install" command in a terminal window.